# Resetting MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, password

I'm a rookie using MySql Workbench 6.3 CE on Windows 10. Before I could even try to open my first data table to begin learning SQL, I've managed to forget my password. Can someone help me re-set it step-by-step? I've looked at other posts instructing me to use command line. I've tried to do that, and so far, I've had no luck. Any advice would be appreciated!